# Is the compiler placing memory on the heap?

Tags: c, memory

I don't understand why the following C code works (prints '53').  I thought that *int a* would be placed on the stack and wiped away as soon as foo() exits.  If the compiler is instead placing *int a* on the heap, is there a way to tell it not to?

```
#include "stdio.h"

int * foo()
{
  int a = 53;

  int * b = &a;

  return b;
}

int main(void)
{
  int * c = foo();

  printf("%d\n",*c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what happens. This program has undefined behavior.

Comment: You are just lucky?!. `a` aka `b` was on the stack - now you live in the world of undefined behaviour

Comment: You need to call another function.  Your stack pointer hasn't had a reason to overwrite it with anything else.

Comment: ... indeed if you put `printf("a = ");` before `printf("%d\n",*c);` you get a wrong answer. That can also happen if an interrupt occurs before you can use that "dead" memory.

Comment: this is `c++` but the same concepts apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer `a` is stored on the stack.  The reason this works is that function `foo` returns the address of `a` and function `main` dereferences this address to print it before the contents of `a`'s address are overwritten.  This program works by accident in this instance.  If you want to preserve the value of `a` for the life of the program you'll either need to apply the `static` qualifier to `a`'s declaration, or allocate `a` on the heap.